# How do I fully uninstall the Bitcoin Wallet app for Android?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-wallet-app

My phone is rooted and I'm not going to use the Bitcoin Wallet app anymore since I'll be switching to another one. My problem is, I can't seem to find where the downloaded blockchains are stored. If I'm not mistaken it's supposedly gigabytes big but I can't find it anywhere on my phone. I'm pretty sure the first time I opened up the app, it appeared to be downloading them.

Can someone tell me what directories I should delete to ensure that the app is fully removed from my phone. (I just don't want rogue data lying around and taking up unnecessary space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the blockchain download by BW has significantly reduced recently, and is only headers at best so you're only looking for a 20-40Mb file not gigabytes.

You should be able to locate the private keys here:

```
/data/data/de.schildbach.wallet/files
```

If you need assistance with accessing your rooted phone (you probably don't) I wrote an article [detailing Bitcoin recovery operations on Android](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2011/12/28/how-to-recover-lost-bitcoins-from-an-android-wallet/) that may provide useful supporting information.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is uninstall the app. Android will take of everything and remove all data owned by the app. You should keep a backup of your wallet though, just in case someone reuses one of your addresses to send you money.